# How to pass a mutable list as a parameter of a function (kotlin)

Tags: kotlin, user-input, bubble-sort, mutable

I am trying to make a function bubbleSort() that **takes a mutable list** of x(given by user) indexes **as a parameter**. So far the program is as follows:

The following code cannot be modified:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var list = mutableListOf<Int>()
    print("Please Enter the Total Number of Elements :")
    var number = readLine()!!.toInt()
    for (i in 1..number) {
        print("Please enter the $i Element :")
        var value = readLine()!!.toInt()
        list.add(value)
    }
    val sorted = bubbleSort(list)
    println("The Sorted List in Ascending Order : $sorted")
}
```

Any change/addition must be included inside the bubbleSort() function after main().

I am struggling to understand how to pass the list with total x indexes and certain y values in each index into the bubbleSort() function. Please any feedback on how to start or a hint would be much appreciated. I am completely new to Kotlin and sorry for any misunderstanding on my question as English language is not my native.

I am aware of the logic in bubble sorting array(s). My main issue is the syntax in Kotlin and the fact I could not find sufficient sources online that could assist me on this main question (How to pass a mutable list as a parameter of a function).

Comment: Your `main` method has a parameter of type `Array<String>`.  Your `bubbleSort` method should have a parameter of type `MutableList<Int>`.  There's nothing super complicated here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fun bubbleSort(list: MutableList<Int>) {

}
```